# JSON parse error unexpected token

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, parsing

JSON data is something in this format.

```
[{
    "_id": "5b706faf2605576fefb9ae9c",
    "index": 0,
    "guid": "46850469-5924-4966-b7d6-92125444cf98",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$2,983.78",
    "friends": [{
            "fid": 0,
            "fname": "Sondra Fields"
        },
        {
            "fid": 1,
            "fname": "Sondra"
        },
        {
            "fid": 2,
            "fname": "Fields"
        }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello,",
    "favoriteFruit": "apple"
}]
```

I am trying to get friends "fid" and "fname" but having the hard time doing so. 
I am doing something like this.

```
var dat = { array: data }
var actual = dat.array.reduce((p, n, index) => p.concat(n[index - 1]))
```

initially data is in "data" variable. by doing this `console.log((actual.friends));` I got the following result.

```
  [ { fid: 0, fname: 'Sondra Fields' },
  { fid: 1, fname: 'Sondra' },
  { fid: 2, fname: 'Fields' } ]
```

Unable to further extract the data. Thank you

Comment: json is not encapsulated in brackets

Comment: JSON is a string. Until you parse that string, you'll only be able to use string functions to deal with it. If `data` is the result of calling `JSON.parse()` on a string, then it is no longer JSON and is in fact a JavaScript object (an array in your case).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: It’s unclear what your actual problem is. Please provide actual runnable code (including data), ideally as a jsfiddle or runnable code snippet. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

By Iterating over `actual.friends` you can get the value of `fid` and `fname`.

```js
data=[
{
    "_id": "5b706faf2605576fefb9ae9c",
    "index": 0,
    "guid": "46850469-5924-4966-b7d6-92125444cf98",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$2,983.78",
    "friends": [
        {
            "fid": 0,
            "fname": "Sondra Fields"
        },
        {
            "fid": 1,
            "fname": "Sondra"
        },
        {
            "fid": 2,
            "fname": "Fields"
        }
],
    "greeting": "Hello,",
    "favoriteFruit": "apple"
  }
]

var dat = { array: data }
var actual = dat.array.reduce((p, n, index) => p.concat(n[index - 1]))
actual.friends.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element.fid,element.fname);
});
```

or

```
data.forEach(function(ele) {
ele.friends.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element.fid,element.fname);
  });
});
```

```js
data=[
{
    "_id": "5b706faf2605576fefb9ae9c",
    "index": 0,
    "guid": "46850469-5924-4966-b7d6-92125444cf98",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$2,983.78",
    "friends": [
        {
            "fid": 0,
            "fname": "Sondra Fields"
        },
        {
            "fid": 1,
            "fname": "Sondra"
        },
        {
            "fid": 2,
            "fname": "Fields"
        }
],
    "greeting": "Hello,",
    "favoriteFruit": "apple"
  }
]

data.forEach(function(ele) {
ele.friends.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element.fid,element.fname);
  });
});
```